# How to remove entries from NO_PROXY in Linux environment?

Tags: linux, proxy

In a Linux environment I have the variable `NO_PROXY` for example set to something like

```
docker:2375,docker:2376,169.254.169.254,localhost,127.0.0.1,*.test.ch,test.ch,10.80.0.0/16,10.92.0.0/12,192.168.0.0/16,10.96.0.0/12,10.96.0.1,*svc.cluster.local,*.svc,svc.cluster.local,svc
```

Is there a way to remove the two entries `*.test.ch` and `test.ch` to change that variable to

```
docker:2375,docker:2376,169.254.169.254,localhost,127.0.0.1,10.80.0.0/16,10.92.0.0/12,192.168.0.0/16,10.96.0.0/12,10.96.0.1,*svc.cluster.local,*.svc,svc.cluster.local,svc
```

i.e. to leave all other settings the same, whatever they are?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `sed` on the command line, e.g. in `bash`:

```
sed -e "s/\*\.test\.ch,//g" -e "s/test\.ch,//g")
```

The `sed` commons consists of two expressions substituting the strings `*.test.ch` and `test.ch` as mentioned in the question. They will be replaced with an empty string.

Test session in bash:

```
export NO_PROXY="docker:2375,docker:2376,169.254.169.254,localhost,127.0.0.1,*.test.ch,test.ch,10.80.0.0/16,10.92.0.0/12,192.168.0.0/16,10.96.0.0/12,10.96.0.1,*svc.cluster.local,*.svc,svc.cluster.local,svc"

echo $NO_PROXY
docker:2375,docker:2376,169.254.169.254,localhost,127.0.0.1,*.test.ch,test.ch,10.80.0.0/16,10.92.0.0/12,192.168.0.0/16,10.96.0.0/12,10.96.0.1,*svc.cluster.local,*.svc,svc.cluster.local,svc

export NO_PROXY=$(echo $NO_PROXY | sed -e "s/\*\.test\.ch,//g" -e "s/test\.ch,//g")

echo $NO_PROXY
docker:2375,docker:2376,169.254.169.254,localhost,127.0.0.1,10.80.0.0/16,10.92.0.0/12,192.168.0.0/16,10.96.0.0/12,10.96.0.1,*svc.cluster.local,*.svc,svc.cluster.local,svc
```